# What is the difficulty in extending geometrodynamics to non-abelian fields?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, group-theory, yang-mills, kaluza-klein

In an attempt to widen my own horizons I've decided to educate myself in Wheeler's Geometrodynamics.

In the so-called "already unified theory" one can essentially reproduce an electromagnetic field based solely upon the "footprint" it leaves upon spacetime (to put it crudely).

In seeking out generalizations I continually come across statements that geometrodynamics cannot be extended to fields with nonabelian group symmetries (ie.more general yang mills fields).

Why is this? Any explanation or direction towards an article/book explaining this would be greatly appreciated. Off the bat, I can't see why Rainich type conditions for other fields wouldn't exist.

Note, I'm only examining classical geometrodynamics at the moment.

For example, in [this paper](https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/13/657/13657535.pdf) (László Szabó *General Relativity and Gravitation*, January 1982, Volume 14, Issue 1, pp 77–85), the author writes (on page 2, 2nd paragraph, emphasis mine):

> In the case of non-abelian gauge theories the implementation of this programme* **(referring to geometrization of the field as for electrodynamics)** *is impossible since there is no unambiguous relation between field-variables and the space-time geometry as in the case of electrodynamics.

However, this statement doesn't clarify the reasoning at all.

Comment: I suggest to have a look at the recent book [Geometrodynamics of Gauge Fields:
On the Geometry of Yang-Mills and Gravitational Gauge Theories](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-29734-7). Judging by the title only (I haven't read it), it should answer your question. If you do figure it out, please post an answer here.

Comment: @A.V.S.  I ordered that book earlier two days ago! I guess I'm just impatient thank you for letting me know I'm on the right track!